# Hook a section into WooCommerce Emails with customer ID

Tags: php, wordpress, email, woocommerce

I am keen to hook a section into the WooCommerce emails with the customer number (which is the Wordpress user ID).

If I insert the following code directly into the email template file

```
echo $order->user_id;
```

It works just fine, but if I try and hook it in, nothing is returned - except the word 'Hooked' which shows my hook is correct.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_after_order_table', 'lnz_hook_content', 1);

function lnz_hook_content() {

echo 'hooked'; // Test Purposes only
echo $order->user_id;
```

Any thoughts? Replies much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted it. Needed to add the parameter into my new function:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_after_order_table', 'lnz_hook_content', 1);

function lnz_hook_content( $order) {

echo 'hooked'; // Test Purposes only
echo $order->user_id;
```

Comment: Note: **Since WooCommerce 3** use `$order->get_user_id();` or  `$order->get_customer_id();` to get the user ID. You can also get the `WP_User` instance object using `$order->get_user();`