# Woocommerce emails template update and grab a field from users table

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have been trying for weeks but still, I do not understand how to modify a template of an email for woocommerce and get a value (`user_url`) that is in `wp_users`

**What I tried**

First of all I have the standard template of the email "[customer_processing_order](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/emails/class-wc-email-customer-processing-order.php)"
Then when I am inside of this template I try to insert a new action using this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44358666/hook-a-section-into-woocommerce-emails-with-customer-id)

So I understand that I have to add an action basing on that post.
but I still not understand in which part of the code I have to insert it.

Because when I try to add this sample code

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_after_order_table', 'lnz_hook_content', 1);
function lnz_hook_content() {

echo 'hooked'; // Test Purposes only
echo $order->user_id;
```

nothing happens.

I have inserted this sample code in this zone of the code (row 79)

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_details', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email );
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_after_order_table', 'lnz_hook_content', 1);

function lnz_hook_content( $order) {

echo 'hooked'; // Test Purposes only
echo $order->user_id;

add_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_details', 'lnz_hook_content', 1);

function lnz_hook_content( $order) {

echo 'hooked'; // Test Purposes only
echo $order->user_id;
```

[image: This image does not contain "hooked" nor user_id]

Now I think that is not correct because the email that is received when the order is going to be processed neither "hooked" and "user_id "

I do not know what to do. Without having the certainty to modify the template of the email I cannot do anything.

**What I want to achieve**

Understand how to insert custom code in the template of a woocommerce email. It seems easy but I can't find a way to do it.

In this custom code do a query in the database. I would like using the order customer email to retrieve `user_url` that is in the table `wp_users`. In wp_user the customer email is present.

**UPDATE**

Here the whole code of the template

```
<?php

/**

 * Customer processing order email

 *

 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/emails/customer-processing-order.php.

 *

 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you

 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to

 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does

 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and

 * the readme will list any important changes.

 *

 * @see https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/

 * @package WooCommerce/Templates/Emails

 * @version 3.7.0

 */



if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {

    exit;

}



/*

 * @hooked WC_Emails::email_header() Output the email header

 */

do_action( 'woocommerce_email_header', $email_heading, $email ); ?>



<?php /* translators: %s: Customer first name */ ?>

<p><?php printf( esc_html__( 'Hi %s,', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html( $order->get_billing_first_name() ) ); ?></p>

<?php /* translators: %s: Order number */ ?>

<p><?php printf( esc_html__( 'Just to let you know &mdash; we\'ve received your order #%s, and it is now being processed:', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html( $order->get_order_number() ) ); ?></p>



<?php



/*

 * @hooked WC_Emails::order_details() Shows the order details table.

 * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::generate_order_data() Generates structured data.

 * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::output_structured_data() Outputs structured data.

 * @since 2.5.0

 */

do_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_details', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email );





/*

 * @hooked WC_Emails::order_meta() Shows order meta data.

 */

do_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_meta', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email );



/*

 * @hooked WC_Emails::customer_details() Shows customer details

 * @hooked WC_Emails::email_address() Shows email address

 */

do_action( 'woocommerce_email_customer_details', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email );



/**

 * Show user-defined additional content - this is set in each email's settings.

 */

if ( $additional_content ) {

    echo wp_kses_post( wpautop( wptexturize( $additional_content ) ) );

}



/*

 * @hooked WC_Emails::email_footer() Output the email footer

 */

do_action( 'woocommerce_email_footer', $email );


add_action( 'woocommerce_email_after_order_table', 'lnz_hook_content', 10, 4);
function lnz_hook_content( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {
    if( isset( $order ) ){ // Just a safety check
        $user_id = $order->get_customer_id();
        $user_info = get_userdata( $user_id );
        echo $user_info->display_name;
    }
}

do_action( 'woocommerce_email_after_order_table', 'lnz_hook_content', 10, 4);
lnz_hook_content( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email )

<?>
```

Unfortunately the email does not contain the information captured in the hook (That should be the `echo $user_info->display_name;`

Comment: `$order->get_user_id()` is the way to get `user_id`  Every object in the $order object has a 'setter' and a 'getter'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question, assuming that you wish to show user information on your email template, you can do the following.

First you can use any of the hook available in the email template, say `woocommerce_email_after_order_table` hook. The hook has four parameters available `$order`, `$sent_to_admin`, `$plain_text` and `$email`.

You can make use of the `$order` parameter.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_after_order_table', 'lnz_hook_content', 10, 4);
function lnz_hook_content( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {
    if( isset( $order ) ){ // Just a safety check
        $user_id = $order->get_customer_id();
        $user_info = get_userdata( $user_id );
        echo $user_info->display_name;
    }
}
```

You can use `get_customer_id()` to fetch the **customer id** from `$order` which inturn you can use to get userdata.

Tested and this works.

**#UPDATE**

You don't have to make changes to the Email template, as this will get overridden on next WooCommerce plugin update. Hooks are provided inorder for the third parties to make changes to the file content. Add the code above to your theme/child theme functions.php file

location : Theme -> functions.php

Comment: I insert it in the template of the email. Then I made a fake order to test this email. The result is the same of the image I showed in the question. I inserted also at the end of the code do_action( 'woocommerce_email_after_order_table', 'lnz_hook_content', 10, 4);
lnz_hook_content( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) but nothing is showed. I'm uploading the question with the whole code of the template. I am sure to do something wrong, but I cannot understand where is the error

Comment: You shouldn't add this in the template. You can add this to the active theme/child theme functions.php file. Please check the UPDATE part of my answer posted

Comment: Yes now I see something

Comment: @ragioniere96 Are you able to see your added content. Happy to help. If i was helpful, then please upvote my answer